# Formatting Floating Point values to monetary amounts in python

Tags: python, floating-point

I want to format float values to any currency here I am converting to dollar currency.

```
import math

def float_money(number):
    return '$' + str(format(math.floor(number * 100) / 100, ',.2f'))

print "Formatting Floating Point Values To $ Dollar Currency"

a = input("How Many Floating Point Values Your want To Enter: ")

b = [float(input("Please Enter Floating Point Values: ")) for i in range(a)]

print float_money(b)
```

If I didn't give that `a` and `b` variable and give `b = 333.323234` then it will print and give output as `$333.32....`

But here in `b` variable all the float numbers are stored in a list like `[3334.33, 3244.342, 4234.42334]`. How to get output in all dollar values?

Answer (score 2):

```
float_values = [3334.33, 3244.342, 4234.42334]
str_values = ['${0:7.2f}'.format(val) for val in float_values]
```

Result:

```
['$3334.33', '$3244.34', '$4234.42']
```

Answer (score 0):

Print each item in the list:

```
for i in b:
    print float_money(i)
```